Summarise rows based on columns
I have this dataframe that I want to summarise the data by getting results from one row (CODE) and adding it to a new column based on the ID and CODIFICATION_ID columns.
For instance:
   ID         NAME                    AGE    CODE                CODIFICATION_ID
   <chr>      <chr>                   <dbl>  <chr>               <chr>      
 1 J154323    CHARLIE XAVIER          57     T.C50.9-M.8500.3    ICDO     
 2 J154323    CHARLIE XAVIER          57     TisN0M0             TNM     
 3 J154323    CHARLIE XAVIER          57     x                   ZERO        
 4 J156543A   BEN SOLO                54     x                   ZERO       
 5 J156543A   BEN SOLO                54     T3N1M0              TNM       
 6 J15HS65    BARTHOLOMEW SIMPSON     50     T.C50.9-M.8500.3    ICDO        


I want to summarise like this:
   ID         NAME                    AGE    ICDO                TNM       ZERO
   <chr>      <chr>                   <dbl>  <chr>               <chr>     <chr>   
 1 J154323    CHARLIE XAVIER          57     T.C50.9-M.8500.3    TisN0M0    x         
 2 J156543A   BEN SOLO                54     NA                  T3N1M0     x  
 3 J15HS65    BARTHOLOMEW SIMPSON     50     T.C50.9-M.8500.3    NA         NA  


I am trying with library(dplyr), but no luck.
Thank you for your help!

Try using pivot_wider() from the tidyr package, e.g. df %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = c(ID, NAME, AGE), names_from = CODIFICATION_ID, values_from = CODE)? More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57013551/12957340
